# Show that $f(x)$ has a unique global minimum point over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, inequality

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\cos\alpha x + \sin\beta x$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real constants with $|\alpha|+|\beta|<1$. Show that $f(x)$ has a unique global minimum point over $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to compute the derivate of $f(x)$:

$f'(x) = x-\alpha\sin \alpha x + \beta \cos \beta x$, and $f''(x) = 1-\alpha^2\cos \alpha x - \beta^2 \sin \beta x$.

I know that if we can show that $f''(x)>0$ then the problem is solved. However, I have difficulty to prove this inequality. Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Note that $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 < 1$.

Comment: $f'' > 0$ is not sufficient to guarantee the existence of a minimum. You should also check $f'(x^*)=0$ for a certain $x^*$ (that of course would be unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from
$$
 \alpha^2 + \beta^2 \le (|\alpha|+|\beta|)^2<1 
$$
that
$$
f''(x) = 1-\alpha^2\cos \alpha x - \beta^2 \sin \beta x \ge 1-\alpha^2 - \beta^2 > 0 \, ,
$$
i.e. $f$ is strictly convex. The existence of a global minimum follows from the fact that
$$
 \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) =+\infty \, ,
$$
and the strict convexity ensures that there is no other (local or global) minimum.